# Which Spring security authentication scheme fits REST API for both mobile and web apps?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I'm building a set of REST APIs with Spring MVC and Security for a set of apps, we have two mobile apps and one webapp(the webapp is a HTML5 single page app so it pretty much standalone).

My question is: which authentication scheme is best for this kind of problem?

What I was thinking of is:

- Use form-login for login with HTTP POST to login url
- Use RememberMe services to maintain a session over time of (month or year) - this is mainly for the mobile apps, where you want user to login only once.

I'm not feeling 100% comfortable with above solution because:
working with cookies in REST API feels awkward to me

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need cookies (or form login) at all if you're dealing with REST? REST should be accessed programatically and therefore there a consuming app would have no problem passing an HTTP BASIC/DIGEST header every time

Comment: You're right, but cookies are the same headers so it's not a big difference. Another thing I wanted to use Spring Security Remember Me filter (I'm lazy :) and avoid implementing my own filter